# C# Richtextbox - Get text size after changing it by scrolling and holding ctrl

Tags: c#, size, richtextbox

I have a richtextbox. When I'm holding control and spin the scroll wheel, the text size is changing.
But how do I get the text size after changing it by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + scroll? `RichTextBox1.Font.Size` is always 8.25.

Google did not help.

Comment: With ctrl+scroll you are making a zoom so changes the ZoomFactor but not the font size (like a magnifying glass, the font size of the paper remain the same but the zoom change)

Comment: Thanks. Now I know a bit more. ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [`ZoomFactor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.zoomfactor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of RichTextBox:

> Gets or sets the current zoom level of the RichTextBox.

That's why you don't see the font size change.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
      float zoom = richTextBox1.ZoomFactor;
      if ((zoom * 2 < 64) && (zoom / 2 > 0.015625))
      {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Add && e.Control)
            {
                  richTextBox1.ZoomFactor = zoom * 2;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Subtract && e.Control)
            {
                    richTextBox1.ZoomFactor = zoom / 2;
            }
      }
}
```